# Long list cut off and requires piping to more. Occurs only with screen sessions

Tags: gnu-screen, alma-linux

When performing a long list where there is a lot of files, the output is cut off and requires piping to `more`.  It happens when I am logged into a `screen` session.

What settings needs to changed for screen sessions to not require piping to more? OS is AlmaLinux 8.

Comment: If you mean cut  off in  that you can't scroll back in the terminal emulator in which you run the screen terminal emulator (for those that have a scrollback buffer), then that's expected, you need to scroll back within the `screen` terminal emulator itself, which you can do in copy mode (entered with `^A[` by default).

Answer (score 0):

`screen` is a terminal emulator, one with many unique features compared to regular terminal emulators such as `xterm`, `putty` or the Linux kernel virtual terminal: it can be split vertically, horizontally, have several sessions with several "windows", it can be attached/detached to any number of display devices, even attached to none and reattached thereafter, can be automated, process its input/output with external filters, etc.

Another main different is that whilst `xterm`/`gnome-terminal` use X11 or Wayland for its display device and Linux' virtual terminal the frame buffer or VGA console, `screen`'s display device is a *host* terminal, which can be anything including physical terminals, `xterm`, Linux virtual terminal.

It emulates a vt100-like terminal making do with the features available host terminal.

Some of those host terminals do have a scrollback buffer (like the one you get on the Linux virtual terminal with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp/Down</kbd>, or the ones operable with a scroll bar on some X11 terminal emulators), but `screen`'s terminal emulation operates in its own "windows" and never lets the host terminal scroll. The fact that you can split the screen, attach and reattach makes it obvious that it couldn't work that way.

`screen` however has its own scrollback buffer, one per window. That buffer is available wherever the screen session is attached to and remains available even when you detach it completely.

You can adjust its size with the [`scrollback` and `defscrollback` screen commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Scrollback.html#Scrollback). You can access it from the [copy mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Copy.html) entered with `<prefix>[`, `<prefix>^[` or `<prefix>ESC`, `<prefix` being `^A` by default.

From within the copy mode you can scroll up or down with the arrow or pageup/down keys or hjklHL vi-style motion keys, and more, select and copy text from there, send the selection to files, even define your own actions.

It's also possible to log all the output history of a screen window with `<prefix>H` or send the visible contents of a window with `<prefix>h`, or including the scrollback buffer with `hardcopy -h`.

Answer (score -1):

With "cut off", I assume you mean that you seen just the last part of the output.

`screen` takes over the management of the console, so the scrollbars no longer work.  The most obvious solution is to stop using `screen`, as it seldom works better than using a couple of `xterm` instances.

If you want to scroll through `screen`'s scrollback buffer, then it should be:

- control-A [
- use the arrow keys to scroll back
- escape to exit scrolling

but, to be honest, I don't use `screen` so I copied that of some website.

Or just make the screen larger or the font smaller.

Comment: Control-A escape doesn't work. I use screen for task that takes time to run. When network dropouts task will continue to run as session can be resumed.